# Honda Civic runs, warms up, and dies

Tags: engine, honda, civic

My engine is a b15b2. The car is a 1991 civic lx. Why do I have the three cam marks and the 7 o'clock one instead of the 2 that line up with the head and the up mark?  I changed the belt, but still the car starts fine when it is cold, but after I shut it off, it will not start until it cools **all** the way down. At the time of run temp..  No spark is being generated. It was running fine a week ago.  I ordered a coil because there were 1.8 ohms between terminals A and B, which is too much from what my book says. Help!